# How to send local file from Flask to Reactjs

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I have React JS as frontend and Flask as backend for my application. The idea is that the user upload image to react, then transfer to process in Flask and then Flask return the processed image back to React for display.

To send file from Flask to React, I saved the image in a local folder. So the order looks like this:

```
--node_modules,public,src // React files
--api  //Flask files
  -upload_image
  -app.py
  -...
```

So in Flask, I will send the url of the image from my local server to React like this:

```
@app.route('/get-cut-image',methods=["GET"])
def get_cut_img():
    if path_is_valid:
        return "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/upload_image/img.png"
    else:
        return "No valid path"
```

and in React, I use axios to call the server:

```
export default class Body extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: "", 
      result: false,
      upload: true,
    };
    this.getDatas = this.getDatas.bind(this);
  }
  getDatas() {
    try {
      const dataImage = axios.get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-cut-image"
      );
      this.setState({
        images: dataImage.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    this.setState({result: true, upload: false});

  }
  render() {
    return (
        <img src={this.state.images}></img>
    );
  }
```

However, the server send the right url to image folder, however, I cannot get the url in client. Any help?

EDIT:
So I figure out that localhost:3000/ is the public folder of react. So my directories looks like this:

```
--node_modules,public,src // React files
--api  //Flask files
  -app.py
```

I have another function that process the image, and save the image to the `public` folder

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   img_BGRA = <some_processing> #return PIL image
   img_BGRA.save(<home/user/.../public/filename.png>)
```

When I try to do so, in my react page crashes and restart again.

Comment: `axios.get` is async; you need `async getDatas() {` and `const dataImage = await axios.get(...);`

Comment: @ChrisG : I think it can find the path, but cannot show the image ```<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>``` Is my path wrong?

Comment: @ChrisG: Edit, I fix the path, should only be ```upload_image/img.png```, but ```img src=path</img>``` cannot preview the image

Comment: Right, first of all: has your flask server a static route where the image can be requested? If you put `http://localhost:5000/upload_image/img.png` into the browser's address bar, do you see the image? If not, you have to fix that first, independent of any React/JS code. Next, think about what you want to serve. Why not have your `get-cut-image` route serve the image directly?

Comment: @ChrisG can you explain about serving the get-cut-image directly?

Comment: also, how can I find the directory of ```localhost:500``` in my personal computer?

Comment: what is `path_is_valid`? ... what browser displays on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-cut-image`?

Comment: @xadm path_is_valid displays the path to the file in my local computer. ```http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-cut-image``` shows the processed image( the right image that I need to show)

Comment: you mean right url .... axios call ... in network dev tools ... response is the same? encoded as ...? `console.log(dataImage.data)` ?

Comment: @xadm it shows http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/upload_image/img.png

Comment: missing call to `getDatas()` in `componentDidMount` ? `console.log("url ", this.state.images)` in `render()` before `return` - should be called twice

Comment: There is no directory of `localhost:5000`; Flask doesn't work like PHP. What you do is set up routes, then send back HTML or files or JSON. There usually is a folder for static content however, like icons, stylesheets and the like. This folder is passed as `static_url_path` when you call `app = Flask(...)`

Comment: @ChrisG I found out that reactjs only access to its `public` folder, is there any way for flask to save images in that folder?

Comment: @ChrisG I tried to but get Aborted request

Comment: 1. put relevant code in the question 2. flask is python, it can save files anywhere on the hard drive

Comment: @ChrisG I added the code. Yes, flask can save the images there, but my React website was crashing and restart again.

Comment: "I found out that reactjs only access to its public folder" vs " axios call ... in network dev tools ... response is the same?" - it wasn't?

Comment: @xadm They are the same, but I have problem displaying the image later using img src

Comment: you shouldn't save file in react's publish ... your react app can ask other server (or the same but different port) for data and display images from other services ... but CORS and cross site mixed content errors can occure ... if data is ok and react renders right `img src` then it's only matter of serving uploaded data as static content - request is failed in dev tools?

Comment: @xadm The point is if I save my files in another folder, like ```api/folder1```, react cannot access the right path to display on ```img src```

Comment: answer the question - fail or not? it's **almost the same** as is **image** (not urs) is displayed in browser using returned url, is static content (image file request, not uploading api request) handled properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214166/discussion-between-ha-an-tran-and-xadm).